# Move random file using the mv command

Tags: command-line, mv

Simple and short question; is it possible for `mv` to move a random file?

I know `mv` can move all files with a specific extension using `mv *.extension`, but as I'm pretty new to Ubuntu/Linux overall I'm unsure whether `mv` can do this or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the man pages for the `shuf` and `xargs` commands, this might be what you are looking for:

```bsh
shuf -n [Number of files to move] -e [PATH to the files to be moved] | xargs -i mv {} [PATH to the dest]
```

Comment: Right, but I think you want `[PATH to the files to be moved]/*`

Comment: Thank you both. It works perfectly. Is it possible to rename the file that gets moved?

Comment: Well, it depends on `[Number of files to move]` (by the way the question asks for how to move a single file). So `shuf -n 1 -e [PATH to the files to be moved]/* | xargs -i mv {} [PATH to the dest]` would pick one random file from `[PATH to the files to be moved]` and move it to `[PATH to the dest]` (that would miss hidden files though. To include also hidden files: `shopt -s dotglob; shuf -n 1 -e [PATH to the files to be moved]/* | xargs -i mv {} [PATH to the dest]`).

Comment: I see. I'm currently trying to move one random picture to a folder and change the picture name, and then have it moved back to the picture's folder upon my next reboot with some random name, so there aren't any issues with duplicate filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shell-only approach:

```bash
## Save all files in the array $files
files=(*)
## Get a random number between 0 (arrays start counting at 0) and the 
## the number of files -1 (the last file in the array)
rand=-1
until (( $rand < ${#files[@]} && $rand >= 0 )); do rand=$RANDOM; done
## Move the file, renaming as necessary
mv "${files[$rand]}" newfilename
```

You can copy/paste the above directly into your terminal.

---

Alternatively, in Perl:

```
perl -le 'rename $ARGV[int(rand($#ARGV))],newfilename' *
```

The `rename` function simply renames its first argument as its second: `rename orifinal_file new_file`. The `rand` function prints a random fractional number between 0 and the argument given. `$#ARGV` is the number of arguments given to the script, here, all files (and subdirectories) in the current directory. Since `rand` returns fractional numbers, we pass it through `int()` to get an integer. So, `int(rand($#ARGV))` picks one of the indices in the @ARGS array randomly and therefore `$ARGV[int(rand($#ARGV))]` is one of the files.